# What is causing SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF error in underscore template?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF output when using an underscore template to render html in a Backbone application. Here is my template:-

```
<script type="text/template" id="shellmenu-template">
  <div>
    <p>menu template html will go here....</p>
    <div class="menuButtonsContainer">
        <% _.each(menu, function(menuItem){ %>
        <button class="menuButton" id="<%= _.escape(menuItem.id)"><%= _.escape(menuItem.title) %></button>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

It is specifically erroring on this part:-

```
id="<%= _.escape(menuItem.id)"
```

The id attribute is a number, here is the menuItem object:-

```
dataPath: ""
helpType: "default"
id: 0
moduleName: "TestModule"
modulePath: "interaction/test/testmodule"
title: "Test Module Interaction"
```

I have tried making the id a string or making it the title attribute in the underscore template code just to see if I can get a test case working in any shape or form but I am stumped so far. I have a similar template doing pretty much the same thing with no errors.

Any ideas what silliness I am engaging in to cause this? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you didn't close `<%=` with `%>`